# setInterval not working in Chrome and Firefox when window loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

My `setInterval` function does not appear to be working in Chrome and FF, but is working in IE, when I first go to a login page.

I want to detect if a user has requested that their login data is saved as part of the login form. If it is saved, then the login button should be green. At the moment, it is not detecting that the form has remembered the credentials and the button is greyed out:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".busy-dialog").fadeOut(500);
    }, 1000);
    var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
    evt.initEvent("click", true, true);
    window.dispatchEvent(evt);
    setInterval(function () {checkLogin();}, 200);
});
```

Where the `checkLogin` function is simply:

```
function checkLogin() {
    var email = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    if (email != '' && email != undefined && password != '' && password != undefined) {
        $("#loginform .button.primary").attr('disabled', false);
        $("#loginForm .button.primary").prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $("#loginForm .button.primary").attr('disabled', true);
        $("#loginForm .button.primary").prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to avoid using `setInterval` for this use case.

Even if you are going to use it, then you must clear it once the form is validated. Increase the timer interval as well. 200ms is too short and you're triggering the function so many times.

```
var timer = setInterval(checkLogin, 500);
```

In your `checkLogin()` function.

```
function checkLogin() {
    var email = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    if (!!email && !!password) {
        $("#loginform .button.primary").attr('disabled', false);
        clearInterval(timer);
    } else {
        $("#loginForm .button.primary").attr('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

Instead of `setInterval`, you can use `keypress` or `input` event and check if they are filled or not.